# Use HTTP proxy to download ivy dependencies when running Spack

Tags: apache-spark, ivy

Spark can at runtime download extra dependencies, via the `packages` option.

It seems using `ivy` to do that.

**I would like to configure HTTP proxy to download only these files from the web. Is it possible?**

(I dont want to configure proxy for all the java process, only for downloading jars).

---

Running Spark as debug with intellij IDEA led me to

https://github.com/apache/ant-ivy/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/ivy/util/url/BasicURLHandler.java

We could add a proxy here:

```
url.openConnection(PROXY);
```